# Is there a way to create key based on counts in Spark

Tags: python, scala, bigdata, apache-spark

**Note:** This question is related to Spark, and not just plain Scala or Python

As it is difficult to explain this, I would show what I want. Lets us say, I have an RDD A with the following value

```
A = ["word1", "word2", "word3"]
```

I want to have an RDD with the following value

```
B = [(1, "word1"), (2, "word2"), (3, "word3")]
```

That is, it gives a unique number to each entry as a key value. Can we do such thing with Python or Scala?

Comment: You seem to be asking quite a few questions that might be answered more quickly with a read through the Spark API doc (here, http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD, for RDD)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using [`zipWithIndex`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD)?

> Zips this `RDD` with its element indices. The ordering is first based on the partition index and then the ordering of items within each partition. So the first item in the first partition gets index 0, and the last item in the last partition receives the largest index. This is similar to Scala's zipWithIndex but it uses Long instead of Int as the index type. This method needs to trigger a spark job when this RDD contains more than one partitions.

Otherwise, `zipWithUniqueId` seems a good fit as well.

If the order of the index is important, you can always map a `swap` function on the RDD.

Comment: Vow, that is brilliant! But what is the difference b/w ZipWithIndex and ZipWithUniqueId?

Comment: According to the docs, there may exist gaps between the indexes if you use zipWithUniqueId, but it won't trigger a spark job.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, one way is as below:

```
>>> A = ["word1", "word2", "word3"]
>>> B=[(idx+1,val) for idx,val in enumerate(A)]
>>> B
[(1, 'word1'), (2, 'word2'), (3, 'word3')]
```

Comment: This is python code and I don't know what restrictions exist for Python Spark.

Comment: The question is tagged Python and you asked 'Can we do such thing with Python or Scala?'. Why the down vote?